# Setting tabs in upper and lower screen

Tags: android, tabs

hiii..in an activity i want to set 4 tabs on the top and 2 tabs in the bottom section of activity?? i create 4 tabs in top section but unable to create 2 tabs in bottom section, please help me...

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. I don't see how you'd do it using the default tab implementation. You'll have to roll your own

Comment: There's already a limitation that you can't effectively put tabs in the bottom. if you try to do that, you end up messing with the look of the UI. In this case, i feel, it would be better to create tab-like things in the bottom, via code

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html to specify additional tabs anywhere in your views.

So use a TabActivity for the main (4) tabs, and the other ones can be managed by additional code.

Comment: sir please elaborate little more. if i set the contentview for activity as an xml which has tabhost of 4 tabs. than how can i again set a contentview  when i add 2 another tabs from programming.this confused me. so please explain a liitle more.